# How do I find the uniqueness of the repetition of numbers?

Tags: python, list, numbers, unique

An array of integers is given. Write a function that returns true, when each value inthe array occurs unique times.
Example 1:
1)Input: array = [1,2,2,1,1,3]
2)Output: true
Explanation: The value 1 has 3 occurrences, 2 has 2 and 3 has 1. No two values havethe same number of occurrences.

how do i solve? Please,help.

Comment: Post your code, then ask your question about it if you still have one.

Comment: That having been said, you can start by counting the number of occurrences of each number (use a `dict` to store the counts, indexed by the numbers in the input list).  Then create a `set` of the counts.  Return `True` if the length of the `set` is the same as the length of the `dict` (i.e., no duplicates).

Comment: `(lambda x=tuple(map(array.count, set(array))): len(x) == len(set(x)))()` or in python 3.8 `len(x := tuple(map(array.count, set(array)))) == len(set(x))`

Comment: @TomKarzes Please,can you give more information?

Comment: What have you tried? Getting answers written for you on Stack Overflow is not a good way to learn to code.

Comment: Please see [ask], [mcve], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array =  [1,2,2,1,1,3]

exm = {}
for x in array:
    exm.setdefault(x, 0)
    exm[x] += 1

if len(set(exm.values())) == len(set(array)):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
liste = [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]

dict = {}
for elem in liste:
    dict.setdefault(elem, 0)
    dict[elem] += 1

print(len(set(dict.values())) == len(dict))
```

If you need help with that code, just ask me